# Block behavior when being passed as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, metaprogramming

I’ve gone through an example where a block is passed to a method. When this method is called, what is passed as variable into the block is `self`. Let me explain it with an example:

```
module Subject 

    def initialize 
        @observers=[] 
    end

    def add_observer(&observer) 
        @observers << observer 
    end 

    def delete_observer(observer) 
        @observers.delete(observer) 
    end 

    def notify_observers 
        @observers.each do |observer| 
            observer.call(self) 
        end
    end 

end
```

We would use `add_observer` as follows:

```
fred = Employee.new('Fred', 'Crane Operator', 30000)
fred.add_observer do |changed_employee| 
    puts("Cut a new check for #{changed_employee.name}!") 
    puts("His salary is now #{changed_employee.salary}!")
end
```

Is this the rule? When you pass a block as an argument of an instance method, is the variable being passed to the block always ‘self’?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are specifiying with `observer.call(self)`. If you use `observer.call('some_string')` then your `changed_employee`'s value will be `some_string`. You can always use a `debugger` inside the block and see what's going on...

Comment: ...although I would choose a different answer: No.  Generally, your statement is NOT correct.  However, in your example, that statement IS correct.

Answer (score 0):

> It is this the rule? When you pass a block as an argument of an instance method, is the variable being passed to the block always ‘self’?

No. The argument passed to block is whatever you pass to the block as argument.

Have you ever used arrays in Ruby? Then you would know that `Array#each` most certainly does *not* pass `self` to the block, but rather the individual elements of the array.

The reason why `self` is passed to the block here, is because you pass it:

```
observer.call(self)
#             ^^^^
```